# JPA query with join to ElementCollection

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am working an a project with Spring JPA. In it, have a Person Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "person")
public class Person {
  
  @Id
  private UUID id;
  
  @Column
  private String firstName;

  @Column
  private String lastName;
  
  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @CollectionTable(name = "cities_must", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"))
  @Column(name = "city")
  private Set<String> citiesMust;

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @CollectionTable(name = "cities_optional", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"))
  @Column(name = "city")
  private Set<String> citiesOptional;

  @Column
  @CreationTimestamp
  private Instant creationTimestamp;
 
}
```

Now, in the Person repository, there already exists this derived query below:

QUERY1:

```
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "citiesMust", "citiesOptional"})
    List<Person> findDistinctByCitiesMustContainingAndCitiesOptionalNotContains(String mustCity, String optionalCity);
```

I now need to create a method in the repository where I need to, in additional to the above logic, group persons by their last name and return the latest person in the group based on creation timestamp. So, not knowing where to start I decided to first see what query hibernate was running for the above derived query, based on which I created the below:

QUERY2:

```
@Query(
value = """
select distinct p1_0.id, p1_0.firstName, p1_0.lastName, p1_0.creation_timestamp, cm1_0.person_id, cm1_0.city, co1_0.person_id, co1_0.city
from person p1_0
left join cities_must cm1_0 on p1_0.id = cm1_0.person_id
left join cities_optional co1_0 on p1_0.id = co1_0.person_id
where ?1 in (select cm2_0.city from cities_must cm2_0 where p1_0.id=cm2_0.person_id)
  and ?2 not in (select co2_0.city from cities_optional co2_0 where p1_0.id=co2_0.person_id)
""",
nativeQuery = true
)
List<Person> testQuery(String mustCity, String optionalCity);
```

My thought process was that I would simply create the above native query and add the following condition to the above at the end

```
and p1_0.creation_timestamp = (select max(creation_timestamp) from person where lastName = p1_0.lastName)
```

But when I run QUERY2 above, hibernate gives the exception, "Unable to evaluate the children renderer expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.". I don't really know what to change here, because the QUERY2 that I created is based on the actual query hibernate is running against the db for the method in QUERY1.
I want to be able to modify that to a custom query so I can add the additional logic and create the new query I require.